# Scan directory tree efficiently by date

Tags: php, filter, scandir

What's the most efficient way to grab a list of new files after a given date in php, or perhaps using a system call?

I have full control over how the files are stored as I receive them, so I thought maybe storing them in a folder structure like year/month/day/filename would be best, then all I have to do is scan for the directories greater than or equal to the date I want to retrieve using scandir and casting the directory name to int values.  But I am not sure if I'm missing something that would make this easier/faster.  I'm interested in the most efficient way of doing this as there will be a lot of files building up over time and I don't want to have to rescan old directories.  Basically the directory structure should lend itself well to efficient manual filtering but I wanted to check to see if I'm missing something.

Simple example usage:

```
'2012/12/1' contains files test1.txt, test2.txt
'2012/12/2' => test3.txt, test4.txt
'2011/11/1' => test5.txt
'2011/11/2' => test6.txt
```

If I search for files on or after 2011/11/2, then I want everything except test5.txt to be returned.

Thanks in advance for any insight!

edit: the storing and actual processing of files are two separate processes, so I can't just process them as they come in which would obviously be the best solution.

Comment: I use this technique frequently, often storing millions of files in a single tree. Note that I 0-pad the dates, so I would have `2013/01/01` in order to make things sort properly even as strings.

Comment: Gabe, so, you are saying that my planned way of accessing changed files makes sense?  Pseudo code would be to list all years in the directory and consider only those on or after the date I'm interested in; same for month and day.  If yes then create an answer for it so I can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking I create directories like `YYYY/MM/DD` to store my files, often with another level for different sources. Sometimes I'll use `YYYY-MM/DD` or something similar. Note that there are only 3652 days in a decade, so you could even have a single level like `YYYY-MM-DD` and not get directories that are so large that they're hard to work with. If you have a filesystem that indexes directories, you can easily have 10s of thousands of files in a directory, otherwise one thousand should probably be your upper limit.

To process the files, I don't bother doing any actual searching of directory names. Since I know what date I'm interested in, I can simply generate the paths and scan only the directories containing files in the proper date range.

For example, let's say I want to process all files for the past week:

```
for $date = today() - 7 to today():
    $path = strftime("%Y/%m/%d", $date)
    for $filename in getFiles($path):
        processFile($path, $filename)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful and had some good ideas.  I ended up doing something very similar to your pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are on either linux or mac based on how you wrote your path.

The find command can return a list of files modified (or accessed) within a certain date.

```
// find files that were modified less than 30m ago
$filelist = system("find /path/to/files -type f -mmin -30");
```

I think system calls should be used sparingly since they reduce portability.

Storing in directories as you mentioned makes sense as it will reduce the search space.

Comment: This is fine if you have maybe 1000 or 10,000 files -- but what if you have millions of files?

Comment: @gabe yes, /path/to/files could include the timestamp directory structure.  It's not mutex with storage choice.